# DateTime, +1 week and -1 week not working the same

Tags: php, datetime

I have a couple of functions juggling back and forth with weeks.

One surprising, and unwanted, behavior I discovered was this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate(2014, 52);
$date->modify('+1 week');
echo date('YW', $date->getTimestamp()) . '<br />';

$date->setISODate(2014, 01);
$date->modify('-1 week');
echo date('YW', $date->getTimestamp()) . '<br />';
```

This code prints:
201401
201352

My expectation was:
201**5**01
201352

Three questions:

1) Have I done something wrong in the code above or is there an inconsistent behavior between "+1 week" and "-1 week" (as in year not being stepped in the first case)?

Answer from comment:
It never increase/decrease year but week 1 happens to start in December 2013 thus it seems like it decrease year in the "-1 week" example.

2) If there is an inconsistency, can I trust the code will work the same on various platforms and PHP versions?

Answer:
No inconsistency (see accepted answer)

3) Is there a better way to step 1 week backward and forward in time (input is year and week, output is also year and week)?

bonus question) If there actually is an inconsistency, does anyone know why?

Answer:
No inconsistency, see answer on number 1 for explanation

Comment: I suggest you print the full date (in "normal" year/month/day as well as weekyear/week) before you modify it. That may well help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Great idea, didn't think of that... and yes. Added:

echo date('YW', $date->getTimestamp()) . '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d', $date->getTimestamp()) . '<br />';
... before each modify. Output:
201452
2014-12-22
201401
201301
2013-12-30
201352

Which means it doesn't step year but works in the first case because week 52 starts in December and thus year is already decreased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Y** is year from the date
- **o** is ISO-8601 year number
- **W** is ISO-8601 week number of year

if using 'W' for the week number use 'o' for the year.

Comment: This may clarify: http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php